# Generate the HTML template equivalent of a twig file?

Tags: html, twig, twig-extension

I'd like to know if it's possible to have `{filename}.html` generated for every `{filename}.html.twig`? I know one solution is to copy and paste the source code from the browser, but is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to cache the twig output?

Comment: Yes, you worded it better than I could @DarkBee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such solution, I think, will satisfy your needs.

`curl www.yoururl.com > /path/to/yourfolder/file.html`

Have a look below story, if you interested in.

**Story**

A few months ago, i was working on a yii2 project. The index page was loading in 3 seconds because of response from external services. Cloudflare and other caching scenarios weren't succeeded - I came up with 2.5 seconds best.

After 2-3 days of thinking period, I found a nasty solution :) 
Created a cache-less, fresh  version of homepage and wrote a crone job, to fetch the contents of that page and write into index.html file inside public (in yii2 `web`) folder in every 2 minutes.

Other pages were ok - (<0.2s), so didn't wrote anything for them.

All I've done, was

`curl www.example.com > /path/to/web/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create these file automatically with each render, then I suggest to overwrite the default render method of the `Twig_Environment` and create an instance of your custom class to init Twig

```
class MyTwigEnvironment extends \Twig_Environment {
    public function render($name, array $context = array())
    {
        $html = $this->loadTemplate($name)->render($context, $site_id);
        file_put_contents('path/to/cache/folder'.$name.'.twig', $html);
        chmod('path/to/cache/folder'.$name.'.twig', 0664);
        return $html;
    }   
 }
```

---

```
$twig = new MyTwigEnvironment($loader, $options);
echo $twig->render('some_template.html');
```

Comment: Where would I create the instance? (Very new to twig) @DarkBee

Comment: Are you using `twig` standalone or with `symfony`, `silex`, ... ?