# Twig: Is it possible to cache as full HTML?

Tags: php, caching, twig, smarty

I have used Smarty for a lot of years. And now I am developing a project using Twig template system.

Smarty allows generate a cache with the full HTML output for a template or for includes:

> http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/caching.tpl
>   http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.tpl

I have been reading the Twig documentation, but I don't see any about this kind of cache.

Guys, do you know if this HTML cache is available in Twig?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate the HTML template equivalent of a twig file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645498/generate-the-html-template-equivalent-of-a-twig-file)

Comment: @darkbee, but I am looking for a native implementation.

Comment: There is no native HTM cache - Twig caches its templates in pure `PHP`